# Copy Word Macro to Multiple Computers using Template

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have created a custom Macro for our organization that I'm trying to share with other users.  I figured the easiest way to do this for the non-power users was to copy the macro to another template (other than normal.dotm) and place that file in their template directory.  I have created the new template, saved it and then copied it to another computer however when the user opens it up, they cannot see the macro.  Does the user have to copy the macro from the new template to their normal.dotm template before they can use it?

Is there another or easier way to share the macro with multiple users?  Any help/suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be useful to know which version of Word is involved in your company?

Should the users be using the template to create new documents? Or should the macro be available for "all" documents?

The approach you describe is for the first scenario and the macro will only be accessible when a document created from the template has the focus. For the other scenario the template should be placed in the user's STARTUP folder so that it loads automatically when Word starts.

You might also consider adding a Ribbon customization to the template that runs the macro. (EDIT: See this discussion [Word 2010: How do I attach a ribbon button to a template using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32988202/word-2010-how-do-i-attach-a-ribbon-button-to-a-template-using-vba/32989549#32989549))

When you say the users cannot "see" the macro: where are they looking? Is it possible that their security settings are blocking macros? Have you checked in File/Options/Trust Center/Trust Center Settings/Macros Settings?

Comment: I just came back here to delete the post because I realized that I was not saving the .dotm in the STARTUP folder but in the Templates folder.  Once I did that, I was able to see the macro show up on the other computer on all documents.  Is it easy to create the customized Ribbon on the new template?  I created customized ribbons but I'm not sure where they're being pulled from.  I will have to go back and do some more testing.

Comment: Hi Mark
Take a look at the discussion in the link I provided, that gives fairly detailed information. In a nutshell, all Ribbon customizations provided by templates plus any COM add-ins will be displayed "in parallel". Ribbon customizations in templates attached to docs will display only for those docs. If you hover the mouse pointer over a custom control you'll see the name of the template/add-in providing it.

Comment: Thank you Cindy.  I am going to investigate that a little further on my home computer since my company does not allow me to download the file.  You have been helpful in pointing me in the right direction.  Thanks again!